# Automatic font size decrease of display after reload

Tags: bug

I have noticed that once an answer is entered the displayed font is larger than usual. But after a reload it becomes the ordinary font size. Not a big issue but was wondering.

Comment: Can you post some screen shots?

Comment: I believe that was reported on meta at least once before. I can't spare the time to find the thread right now, though.